# The integral over a subset is smaller?

Tags: real-analysis

In a previous question I had $A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty R_k$ where $R_k$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$ are rectangles I then proceeded to use the following inequality $\left|\int_A f\right| \le \left|\int_{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty R_k} f \right|$ which I am not really certain of. Does anyone know how to prove it? If its wrong what similar inequality should I use to prove the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403936/riemann-integral-over-a-set-of-measure-zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is not true in general (think of an $f$ that is positive on $A$ but such that it is negative outside $A$). But it does hold if $f\geq 0$. This is not an obstacle to you using it, because you would just have to split your function in its positive and negative part.

Comment: I was thinking of using $| \int_A f| \le \int_A |f| \le \int_{ \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty R_k} |f|$ since $|f|>0$ and using $\sup |f|$ instead of $|\sup f|$ which doesn't change much

Comment: @user63697: You mean $|f|\geq 0$, and the inequalities in your comment are correct.  What do you mean by "using $\sup |f|$ instead of $|\sup f|$ which doesn't change much"?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I'm referring to the linked question.

Comment: @user63697: Thank you, that might help me guess, but doesn't really answer my question.  My guess is that it will be helpful for you use the inequality $|\sup f|\leq\sup|f|$.  "Doesn't change much" is vague, and presently meaningless to me out of context.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I mean this inequality $|\int_{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty R_k} f |\le |\sup f| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(R_k)$ will be replaced by $\int_{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty R_k} |f| \le \sup |f| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(R_k)$ so instead of setting $|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(R_k) < \epsilon / |\sup f|$ I set it to be less than $ \epsilon / \sup |f| $ . I mean it doesn't change much in the way the result is reached.

Comment: @Jonas: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

For $A \subset B$, $$
  \left|\int_A f\right| \leq \left|\int_B f \right|
$$
is true if either $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in B$, or $f(x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in B$.

For a counter-example if this isn't the case, let $f(x) = x$, $A = [0,2]$, $B=[-2,2]$. Then $$
   \left|\int_A f\right| = 2 > 0 = \left|\int_B f \right| \text{.}
$$

In particular, you thus always have that $$
  \int_A |f| \leq \int_B |f| \
$$
if $A \subset B$.