# Nonnegative measurable function on measure zero set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function from $X$ to $R$.

Then, for $\mu$$(A)=0$, $\int_A f d\mu$=0?

I think by using increasing simple function to $f$ and Monotone convergence theorem,

it's true but i'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\chi_{A_i}$ be a simple function with $0\leq s\leq f$. Then, $$\int_As\,d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\mu(A\cap A_i)=0.$$ Since this holds for all those $s$, you have that $\displaystyle\int_Af\,d\mu=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought i used wrong thing.... :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it would be true by definition, as you're only interested in simple functions (think what *is* $\int_A f d\mu$).

Answer (score 0):

Let ${s_n}$ be a sequence of simple functions such that $s_{n+1}\geq s_n \geq 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and $s_n \to f$ a.e. Via the Monotone convergence theorem, we have $$\int_Afd\mu=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_As_nd\mu. \ \ \  \ \ \ (1)$$Since $s_n$  is a simple function we infer $s_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m_n}a_{n_k}1_{A_{nk}}$ where the sets $A_{nk}$ are measurables and $1_{A_{nk}}$ is the characteristic function of $A_{nk}$, in consequence $$\int_As_nd\mu=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m_n}a_{n_k}\mu(A_{nk}\cap A)=0, \ \ \ (2)$$ because $0\leq\mu(A_{nk}\cap A)\leq \mu(A)=0$. From (1) and (2) we conclude $$\int_Afd\mu=0$$

Answer (score -1):

I could be missing something obvious, but...

$f1_A = f1_{\emptyset} \ \text{P-a.s.}$ and $f1_{\emptyset} = 0$

$\implies E[f1_A] = E[f1_{\emptyset}] = E[0] = 0$

Edit: Ah I see what I'm missing. The 2 statements are actually equivalent. Yeah just refer to the other answers.

['Almost sure equality implies same expectation' is equivalent to 'integral over null set is zero.' What's equivalent to 'almost sure implies (...)'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4634076/almost-sure-equality-implies-same-expectation-is-equivalent-to-integral-over)

[Integral over null set is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293801/integral-over-null-set-is-zero/4032946#4032946)