# Monotonicity with expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I think the following is true but I cannot prove it.

Let $Z_1, Z_2$ are two random variables defined on the same sample space $\Omega$. Suppose that $Z_1(\omega) < Z_2(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in \Omega_0$ and $Z_1(\omega) = Z_2(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in \Omega\setminus\Omega_0$. We have:

If $P(\Omega_0)=0$, i.e. $Z_1=Z_2$ almost surely, then $E(Z_1)=E(Z_2)$.

If $P(\Omega_0)>0$, then $E(Z_1)<E(Z_2)$.

Could you show if it holds or not?

Comment: If you define $X(\omega) = Z_2(\omega) - Z_1(\omega)$ then $X(\omega)\geq 0$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$. You might use the Markov inequality on the random variable $X$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that if $f \ge 0$ then $\int f d \mu = 0$ **iff** $f$ is zero ae. $[\mu]$?

Comment: @Michael: I use that inequality and prove it.

Comment: @Michael: I am wondering what if we assume $P(X(\omega)\geq 0)=1$ instead of $X\geq 0$?

Comment: Sets of probability 0 do not affect expectations, so the result is the same. Equivalently you could define a new RV $Y=\max[X,0]$ which is always nonnegative, and $E[Y]=E[X]$.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
\mathsf{E}Z_1=\int_{\Omega}Z_1(\omega)\mathsf{P}(d\omega)=\int_{\Omega_0}Z_1(\omega)\mathsf{P}(d\omega)+\int_{\Omega\setminus\Omega_0}Z_1(\omega)\mathsf{P}(d\omega).\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Since
$$
\int_{\Omega\setminus\Omega_0}Z_1(\omega)\mathsf{P}(d\omega)=\int_{\Omega\setminus\Omega_0}Z_2(\omega)\mathsf{P}(d\omega),
$$
the result depends on the probability of $\Omega_0$. If $\mathsf{P}(\Omega_0)=0$, then the first integral on the RHS of $\eqref{1}$ is $0$ (see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293801/integral-over-null-set-is-zero)). Otherwise,
$$
\int_{\Omega_0}Z_1(\omega)\mathsf{P}(d\omega)<\int_{\Omega_0}Z_2(\omega)\mathsf{P}(d\omega).
$$